# Not able to override unittest `startTest` and `stopTest` isn’t working correctly in custom test runner when using with –parallel

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

I have override startTest and stopTest from unittest TextTestResult class and used it in my custom test runner. It’s working correctly in normal scenario but not working correctly when using with --parallel flag.

I tried to debug and found the time elapsed b/w startTest and stopTest is coming very very small.
Like 4.8000000000492093e-05 which is incorrect.

Would someone please tell me is it the right hooks for --parallel flag or I have to use some another hook?

Steps to reproduce:

Let's assume the project name of django is `project` and the app is `app`

1. create `custom_test_runner.py` in your django project directory
   and add below code:

```
from time import perf_counter
from unittest import TextTestResult, TextTestRunner
from django.test.runner import DiscoverRunner


class CustomTestRunnerTextTestResult(TextTestResult):
    def __init__(self, stream, descriptions, verbosity):
        super(CustomTestRunnerTextTestResult, self).__init__(stream, descriptions, verbosity)

    def startTest(self, test):
        self.start_time = perf_counter()
        super(CustomTestRunnerTextTestResult, self).startTest(test)

    def stopTest(self, test):
        super(CustomTestRunnerTextTestResult, self).stopTest(test)
        print(f"Time elapsed {str(test)} for {perf_counter() - self.start_time}")


class CustomTestRunnerTextTestRunner(TextTestRunner):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
    resultclass = CustomTestRunnerTextTestResult


class CustomTestRunnerTestRunner(DiscoverRunner):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(CustomTestRunnerTestRunner, self).__init__(**kwargs)
    test_runner = CustomTestRunnerTextTestRunner
```

2. create `test_custom_test_runner.py` in tests folder and add the below code:

```
import time
from django.test import TestCase

class Test1(TestCase):
    def test_1(self):
        time.sleep(2)

class Test2(TestCase):
    def test_2(self):
        time.sleep(2)
```

3. in your `settings.py` add below code

```
TEST_RUNNER = "project.custom_test_runner.CustomTestRunnerTestRunner"
```

4. Now, run  `python manage.py test app.tests.test_custom_test_runner --parallel`

You'll get very small time interval like this:

```
.Time elapsed test_1 (app.tests.test_custom_test_runner.Test1) for 0.00034683300000004635
.Time elapsed test_2 (app.tests.test_custom_test_runner.Test2) for 0.0002126670000004438

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 2 tests in 2.095s
```

But if you ran it without --parallel flag you'll get:

```
.Time elapsed test_1 (app.tests.test_custom_test_runner.Test1) for 2.005363042
.Time elapsed test_2 (app.tests.test_custom_test_runner.Test2) for 2.0043795000000006

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 2 tests in 4.027s
```

Django Version: 3.2.14

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`test_runner.resultclass` (`CustomTestRunnerTextTestResult`) methods are not called in real-time if using `--parallel` flag.

Rather, `parallel_test_suite.runnerclass.resultclass` (`RemoteTestResult`) methods are called, which queue `events` (method calls to `test_runner.resultclass`) to be dispatched together by `parallel_test_suite` (`ParallelTestSuite`) after each test is completed.

Django ticket, Oct 2020: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/32140 (closed as needsinfo)

---

Here's one way to support your requirement:

1. Instead of calling `perf_counter()` directly, implement and call `self._get_time()`, which will try to return the time marked by a `RemoteTestResult` subclass.
2. Provide a method for the `RemoteTestResult` subclass to mark the time via `events`.

```py
class CustomTestRunnerTextTestResult(TextTestResult):
    def __init__(self, stream, descriptions, verbosity):
        super(CustomTestRunnerTextTestResult, self).__init__(stream, descriptions, verbosity)
        self._marked_remote_time = None  # Add this

    def mark_remote_time(self, _test, remote_time):  # For CustomTestRunnerRemoteTestResult events  # Add this method
        self._marked_remote_time = remote_time

    def _get_time(self):  # Add this method
        return self._marked_remote_time or perf_counter()

    def startTest(self, test):
        # self.start_time = perf_counter()  # Change this
        self.start_time = self._get_time()  # to this
        super(CustomTestRunnerTextTestResult, self).startTest(test)

    def stopTest(self, test):
        super(CustomTestRunnerTextTestResult, self).stopTest(test)
        # print(f"Time elapsed {str(test)} for {perf_counter() - self.start_time}")  # Change this
        print(f"Time elapsed {str(test)} for {self._get_time() - self.start_time}")  # to this
```

3. Implement the `RemoteTestResult` subclass, which marks the time via events.

```py
from django.test.runner import RemoteTestResult


class CustomTestRunnerRemoteTestResult(RemoteTestResult):
    def startTest(self, test):
        self.events.append(("mark_remote_time", self.test_index, perf_counter()))
        super().startTest(test)  # Does self.events.append(("startTest", self.test_index))

    def stopTest(self, test):
        self.events.append(("mark_remote_time", self.test_index, perf_counter()))
        super().stopTest(test)  # Does self.events.append(("stopTest", self.test_index))
```

4. Pass the `RemoteTestResult` subclass to `parallel_test_suite.runnerclass` constructor.

```
from functools import partial


class CustomTestRunnerTestRunner(DiscoverRunner):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(CustomTestRunnerTestRunner, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.parallel_test_suite.runner_class = partial(  # Add this
            self.parallel_test_suite.runner_class,
            resultclass=CustomTestRunnerRemoteTestResult,
        )
    test_runner = CustomTestRunnerTextTestRunner
```

Answer (score 1):

Looking at "[Django Writing and running tests¶](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/testing/overview/) and its [`unittest` framework](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#module-unittest), its primary goal is usually to determine if the test cases pass or fail. However, measuring the time taken by each test does not seem to be a built-in feature of the default Django test runner. The default Django test runner does not provide direct hooks for measuring the execution time of individual tests.

When tests are run in parallel, they are executed in separate processes. The `startTest` and `stopTest` methods are called in the context of each individual process, and thus the timing information is not synchronized across these processes.

One possible approach (to accurately measure the time taken by each test when running tests in parallel) is to use a shared variable or a file to store timing information across processes. Here: a multiprocessing `Manager` to share a dictionary across processes. The dictionary is used to store the start time for each test, keyed by the test name, in a `custom_test_runner.py` file:

```py
import time
import unittest
from multiprocessing import Manager, Lock
from django.test.runner import DiscoverRunner
from unittest.runner import TextTestResult

manager = Manager()

# Shared memory resources
shared_data = manager.Namespace()

lock = Lock()

class CustomTestRunnerTextTestResult(TextTestResult):
    def __init__(self, stream, descriptions, verbosity, temp_file):
        super(CustomTestRunnerTextTestResult, self).__init__(stream, descriptions, verbosity)
        self.temp_file = temp_file

    def startTest(self, test):
        with lock:
            shared_data.start_time = time.time()
        super(CustomTestRunnerTextTestResult, self).startTest(test)

    def stopTest(self, test):
        super(CustomTestRunnerTextTestResult, self).stopTest(test)
        with lock:
            elapsed_time = time.time() - shared_data.start_time
            # You can now use the elapsed_time, and if needed, save it using your custom service
            CustomTestRunnerService.save_duration(test=test, elapsed_time=elapsed_time, temp_file=self.temp_file)

class CustomTestRunner(DiscoverRunner):
    def get_resultclass(self):
        return CustomTestRunnerTextTestResult
```

The multiprocessing `Manager` is used to create a shared dictionary. When a test starts, its start time is recorded in the shared dictionary. When a test stops, the time is calculated using the start time from the shared dictionary and the current time.

A lock (`lock`) is used to ensure that only one process at a time can access this shared data. The `startTest` and `stopTest` methods are synchronized with the lock to ensure that the start time and elapsed time are consistently updated and accessed.

This approach should work more accurately in a parallel testing environment because it uses a shared data structure that can be accessed across processes.

Add to your settings.py

```py
# settings.py

TEST_RUNNER = 'path_to_your_module.custom_test_runner.TimeLoggingTestRunner'
```

And launch your test in parallel with [`manage.py`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/django-admin/):

```bash
./manage.py test --parallel
```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254166/discussion-between-vonc-and-abhinav-prakash).